# Customizing modal vs popover (bootstrap)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal, customization, bootstrap-popover

I am writing a basic website for a friend, who makes short films and wants to have a site to present his work.

I have a very easy question but sadly can't find a good (or at least understandable for me) answer for it.

I have a site with 5 pictures in a row, each picture is a short film.

Now I want to make sth. to show the "movie details" like this

[image]

Since I am not a "pro" I was thinking to use a `modal` or `popover`, but I'm struggling trying to customize the layout in both.

So my questions are

1. Can I customize the layout of modals & popovers, not only colors etc?
2. Should I use one before the other? It appears to me that modals are "better" if targeting mobile phones, since popovers normally react to hover actions (not possible in many mobiles)

Here my "testing" CodePend https://codepen.io/rgomez/pen/opvyNq

```css
/* HEADER CSS*/

@font-face {
  font-family: 'CoffeeTin';
  src: url('../fonts/CoffeeTinInitials.eot');
  src: url('../fonts/CoffeeTinInitials.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/CoffeeTinInitials.woff') format('woff'), url('../fonts/CoffeeTinInitials.ttf') format('truetype');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

#myHeader .navbar {
  padding-top: 1rem;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
  background-color: black !important;
}

#myHeader .navbar-brand:hover {
  color: red !important;
}

#myHeader .active {
  font-size: 120%
}

#navbarHome .nav-link {
  font-size: 150%;
  font-family: 'CoffeeTin';
  color: red
}


/* BODY CSS*/

.tooltip>.tooltip-inner {
  background-color: #f00;
  max-width: 1000px
}

.tooltip>.tooltip-arrow {
  border-bottom-color: #f00;
}

.tooltip {
  width: 100%
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%
}

#movies {
  margin-top: 4rem;
  margin-bottom: 4rem
}

#movies img {
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}

#movies img:hover {
  transform: scale(1.5)
}


/*Footer CSS*/

#myFooter {
  background-color: #000000;
  color: white;
}

#myFooter h5 {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

#myFooter a {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#myFooter a:hover,
#myFooter a:focus {
  color: rgb(250, 4, 4);
}

#myFooter .social-networks {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 16px;
}

#myFooter .social-networks a {
  font-size: 32px;
  color: #f9f9f9;
  padding: 10px;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

#myFooter .contact:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #ef1a1a
}

#myFooter .facebook:hover {
  color: #0077e2;
}

#myFooter .google:hover {
  color: #ef1a1a;
}

#myFooter .twitter:hover {
  color: #00aced;
}

#myFooter .btn {
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 0px;
  width: 10rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: .5rem;
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  line-height: 25px;
}
```

```html
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
  <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-108836206-1"></script>
  <script>
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];

    function gtag() {
      dataLayer.push(arguments);
    }
    gtag("js", new Date());

    gtag("config", "UA-108836206-1");
  </script>

  <!-- These meta tags come first. -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="es">

  <head>
    <!-- Include Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->


    <title>Panoja Films - Guillermo Paniagua</title>

    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="assets/icons/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">

    <!-- These meta tags come first. -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="keywords" content="film,director,pelicula,guillermo,paniagua,panoja">
    <meta name="description" content="Guillermo Paniagua - Film Director Personal-Site - PanojaFilms 2017">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <meta name="application-name" content="Panoja Films">

    <meta property="og:url" content="{{pageUrl}}">
    <meta property="og:image" content="{{imageUrl}}">
    <meta property="og:description" content="{{description}}">
    <meta property="og:title" content="{{pageTitle}}">
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="{{siteTitle}}">
    <meta property="og:see_also" content="{{homepageUrl}}">

    <!-- Include the CSS -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nosifer" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--Bootstrap CSS-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/footer.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/body.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/header.css">

    <!-- Include jQuery (required) and the JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
      });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body style="background-color: black">
    <header id="myHeader">
      <a href="index.html">
        <div id="logoHeader" class=" jumbotron-fluid img-fluid" href="#logoHeader" href="index.html" style="background: url(assets/img/logo-banner.jpg); background-size: 100% 100%; height: 15rem"></div>
      </a>
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark sticky-top">

        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarHome" aria-controls="navbarsExampleDefault">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarHome">
          <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
              <a class="nav-link" href="cortometrajes.html">Cortometrajes</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="guiones.html">Guiones</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="fotografia.html">Fotografia</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="about.html">Sobre Mi</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </header>

    <div class="container-fluid" id="movies">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md">
          <img class="img-fluid w-50" src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x250" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-placement="auto" data-trigger="click">
          <p style="color: white">With Modal Test</p>
        </div>
        <!-- The Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
          <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">

              <!-- Modal Header -->
              <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Heading</h4>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
              </div>
              <div id="demo" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

                <!-- Carousel -->
                <ul class="carousel-indicators">
                  <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                  <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                  <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                </ul>

                <!-- The slideshow -->
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                  <div class="carousel-item active">
                    <img src="la.jpg" alt="Los Angeles">
                  </div>
                  <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img src="chicago.jpg" alt="Chicago">
                  </div>
                  <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img src="ny.jpg" alt="New York">
                  </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Left and right controls -->
                <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#demo" data-slide="prev">
                  <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
                </a>
                <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#demo" data-slide="next">
                  <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
                </a>

              </div>


              <!-- Modal body -->
              <div class="modal-body">
                Modal body..
              </div>

              <!-- Modal footer -->
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
              </div>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md">
          <img class="img-fluid w-50" src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x250" alt="Card image cap" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="auto" data-trigger="hover click" data-html="true" title="Cuerdos y Locos" data-content="<h1>TEST</h1>">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md">
          <img class="img-fluid w-50" src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x250" alt="Card image cap" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="auto" data-trigger="hover click" data-html="true" title="Cuerdos y Locos" data-content="<h1>TEST</h1>">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md">
          <img class="img-fluid w-50" src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x250" alt="Card image cap" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="auto" data-trigger="hover click" data-html="true" title="Cuerdos y Locos" data-content="<h1>TEST</h1>">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md">
          <img class="img-fluid w-50" src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x250" alt="Card image cap" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="auto" data-trigger="hover click" data-html="true" title="Cuerdos y Locos" data-content="<h1>TEST</h1>">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <footer id="myFooter" class="">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col  social-networks">
            <h5>Youtube</h5>
            <a href="https://www.youtube.com/user/panojas90" target="_blank" class="google">
              <i class="fa fa-youtube"></i>
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="col social-networks">
            <h5>Facebook</h5>
            <a href="#" class="facebook">
              <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
            </a>
          </div>
          <div class="col social-networks">
            <h5>Twitter</h5>
            <a href="#" class="twitter">
              <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <a class="btn btn-light contact text-center" href="mailto:" role="button">Contáctame</a>
        </div>
        <div class="footer-copyright text-center mt-5">
          <p>© 2017 Copyright
            <a href="http://panojafilms.com">PanojaFilms</a> - All Rights Reserved. </p>
        </div>
      </div>

    </footer>
  </body>
```

Comment: yes a modal takes any valid html and bootstrap which you can further customize with css

Comment: Also i would recommend you use a modal and not a popover for such amount of content which even includes a video.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. Would you mind to show me how to put the carousel in the modal? I am struggling here.....

Comment: simply move the carousel to the modal body. other than that it seems fine

Comment: Ok will try...thx